# AngularJS: Writing to and Reading from textarea with multilines

Tags: html, angularjs, textarea, multiline, sanitize

I can't believe why I can't find anything to this topic ...
I got a form with let's say lastname (input), firstname (input), description (textarea as I want provide several lines). Let's start with the creation of a new object:

Okay, you type something in like

lastname: `fox`

firstname: `peter`

description:

```
what can I say ..
well I'm THE guy

bye
```

This arrives at my Java Spring MVC Backend Controller as `what can I say ..\nwell I'm THE guy\n\nbye` which is fine as I can determine where line breaks are.

So, now I want to edit this object. Thus I want to read the stored data and put it in the form. On Serverside I now edited the description text so that I replaced the `\n` with `<br>` so that I have HTML breaks.

Now I use angular-sanitize (ngSanitize dependency) and use the directive  `ng-bind-html="my.nice.description"`

If I use this on a DIV, everything works fine, HTML gets rendered and I get my breaks. So this works perfectly:

```
<span ng-bind-html="my.nice.description"></span>
```

or one of the following:

```
<div ng-bind-html="my.nice.description"></div>
<p ng-bind-html="my.nice.description"></p>
```

BUT as I want to (re)fill my form so the user can edit his previous input, I still use a textarea. Like this:

```
<textarea ng-bind-html="my.nice.description"></textarea>
```

And this does NOT work in any way. Which means that I get 
's in my text, unrendered.

Though this seems like a ridicilous normal task. It's a form with a simple multiline box, so I want to write my several lines and I want to read them and I want to edit them.
As I am rather a backend guy and not very familiar with HTML and AngularJS I hope that I'm just using the wrong html element or something like this ... Maybe someone can help me out? It's frustrating :(

Thanks in advance and I guess and hope this is not a real hard task :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<textarea>` elements **cannot** contain other elements (in your case, `<br>`'s). They are standalone. You'll have to convert the variable-returned-from-server-containing-`<br>`'s *back* to `\n`'s, and vice versa back and forth. You can use an angular directive that handles that for you.

Comment: I'm not at home right now so I can't try it out, but does that mean it actually works with `\n`? Does textarea accept `\n` as break line?

Comment: Thank you very much, that information was cruical. My problem was that I FIRST looked how to get break lines into a div (like the show page of said object, not the edit page). And there it began that I could do that with switching all `\n`'s to `<br>`'s and bam, done. And then I came to edit page.

Now I realize that I need both, `<br>`'s for show page, `\n` for (re)editing. But that should be no problem :)

Comment: Cool dude! No worries. Hit me up w/ any further frontend questions on #sailsjs @ freenode. On all day and my new years resolution is to help as many devs as possible!!

Answer (score 4):

store 'br' in your model, so you can use ng-bind-html. add a directive to your textarea which makes the conversion between your $viewVale ('\n') and your model.

```
.directive('lbBr', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) {
                return;
            }

            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                return value.replace(new RegExp('\n', 'g'), '<br />');
            });

            ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
                if (value) {
                    return value.replace(new RegExp('<br />', 'g'), '\n');
                }
                return undefined;
            });
        }
    };
});
```